# Magento2 Admin 404

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I am trying to access the admin panel I am getting error 404 not found, I checked through many solutions available in internet for this problem but nothing works. [When I try to access admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iq5e.jpg)

thanks

Comment: I don't think people will be able to help you without you providing how you installed the software, providing the logs, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Hard to find why its happen without seeing your installation process.
But this may help you:

1. You can [reinstall your project](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html)
2. By mistake you forget your admin URL; You can see/change admin URL from

   app/etc/env.php 
   at line no 5.

   ```
   return array (
   'backend' =>
   array (
   'frontName' => 'admin_q76xvk',
   ),
   ```
3. Clean cache/reindexing and delete `var/cache` , `var/page_cache` folder.
4. Make change in `.htaccess` (Just copy this file `pub/.htaccess` to magento root folder)

Comment: @AhmadReshadZazai if it's work Please accept it as answer so it can also help to other people.

Comment: FWIW, this command displays the current URI: `magento info:adminuri`

Comment: Yes also can find by run cmd in root folder  

> php bin/magento info:adminuri